# Apriori Algorithm Running Time

Tags: algorithm, apriori

What is the time complexity of the basic Apriori Algorithm as introduced in 1994? Please cite a reference paper/article if possible to back up the respnose. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This paper by Markus England provides a detailed analysis of the complexity of Apriori:

http://www2.ims.nus.edu.sg/preprints/2005-29.pdf

You can cite it as follows:

M. Hegland, “The Apriori Algorithm – A Tutorial”, Mathematics and Computation in Imaging Science and Information Processing, vol. 11, pp. 209-262, World
Scientific Publishing Co., 2007